# jQuery toggle dropdown with arrow

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

There is dropdown menu that opens using jQuery toggle. For some reason toggle function shows the menu first and then it shows the arrow.
I created a fiddle but dropdown doesn't work there, but it works on my site. How can I fix it?

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/2dtg7xux/]
```

Comment: Put your code in the post please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your fiddle wasn't working is because you didn't add jquery as a framework. To do that you have to click on the gear icon next to the word javascript and select the jquery framework.

I made the animation work as expected by taking the arrow out of the menu and making it do its own animation right before the menu is animated.

This is the markup. I added a container div to hold both the arrow and the subnav, with the arrow on top:

```
<li class="folder">
  <a href="#"  onClick="return false;">Folder</a>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

This is the CSS. I made the arrow have position relative so it is relative to it's container, then adjusted the position to match where it was before, and changed the z-index to 1 so that it is not under the drop shadow of the subnav. I also made it "display: none" so it starts invisible:

```
.subnav{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 23px -2px #707070;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 23px -2px #707070;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 23px -2px #707070;
}
.subnav ul a {
  padding: 6px 20px;
}
.arrow {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And this is the Javascript. It now includes the animation of the arrow before the animation of the subnav:

```
$('.folder a').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.container').find('.arrow').slideToggle();
    $(this).next('.container').find('.subnav').slideToggle();
});
```

Here's the link to the adjusted fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/05pyt1f6/

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!